# Deploying Jetty and NodeJS on the same machine

Tags: node.js, deployment, jetty

Today we have **Jetty** container on our machines.
We are going to introduce **NodeJS** container to our product.

We can deploy NodeJS on the same machine with a different port - that will work, the problem is that we do not achieve hardware isolation between the containers.

The question is: what is the risk of deploying Jetty and NodeJS on the same machines? Did someone has/had experience with that?

Answer (score 1):

Thr is not risk in deploying the Jetty and Node.js in same machine with different ports. We have aproduct, where jetty in node.js running in same machine.

This is common thing to know, its like another process.